# Proper way in SQL stored procedure to append user input to a table and preventing sql injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I have a table in SQL with a `varchar(max)` field that is basically a log that is updated by end users with free-form entry (from a webpage).

How do I protect against SQL injection?  Or perhaps it already is?

```
create proc stored_procedure
@input varchar(max)
as

update mytable
set logfield = logfield + '  ' + @input;
```

It seems like it might be OK (SQL Server 2012). But everything I can read is adamant that you should never concatenate user input even in parameterized stored procedures.

Is there a different way to append the user input?

Comment: What's the application code? [There are many examples of viable work arounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Where is the input to this procedure coming from? What code is calling this procedure elsewhere? That will be the key to determining whether SQL injection or other contamination is possible.

Comment: Kudos to you for actually being concerned about sql injection. Way too many people either are oblivious or think they aren't going to be attacked.

Comment: @TimLeaf this is a stored procedure and the user data is properly parameterized and there is no dynamic sql happening. This procedure is safe from sql injection.

Comment: This procedure itself is safe, yes. However, my point is that if there is application code elsewhere that is running an SQL command to call this procedure, and passing user data, depending on how it is written, that application code might be vulnerable.

Comment: Perhaps the thing you should be sharing here is the code you use to call the SP in your application, as what you have isn't able to be injected into; at least the SQL in the SP as it *is* parametrised.

Comment: The input comes from an SSRS report calling the stored procedure with a single-value text parameter.  At least that's where it is *supposed* to come from.  But one should presume that a hacker could spoof SSRS and just use the stored proc themselves with whatever input they like.

Comment: If you are concerned with hackers connecting to your database somehow, calling a stored procedure is probably the least of your worries. However, if they are merely spoofing an SSRS call, then this should be safe, as long as they are restricted to using the same mechanisms as your currently deployed reports, and each report is accessing data via stored procedure. Unless they could somehow modify the source code, but again, if they could do that, this is probably the least of your concerns.

Comment: We don't get to only do security for things we believe will happen.  My SQL database is internal only with no public access.  Employees connect from inside the office.  I have very very little concern that SQL injection will ever be attempted.  But that's not a good reason to ignore proper security.  I fumble around with SQL stored procedures to enhance the built-in customization that this database is capable of (or more accurately, the off-the-shelf software that uses this database is capable of).  I'm learning about SQL security, stored procedures, and proper protection against injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL injection will only happen on dynamic SQL (either on the SQL Server side or on the application side). Your code is not vulnerable to SQL injection. However, you're updating all the rows in the table. You should limit the update using a WHERE clause.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Though injection can happen in the application when constructing the SQL string  (which I wouldn't suggest is dynamic SQL) and values of things like textboxes are injecting it the string. But this is right; there is no injection threat in the (simplified) SQL the OP has provided us here.

Comment: Luis is correct. Injection would not happen unless is dynamic sql. if you place malicious statements in the field input in the application, it wont matter as long as you don't try to parse it.

Comment: The problem is, this stored procedure is passed an input value. The code that is calling this procedure elsewhere could potentially be vulnerable to SQL injection or other contamination, depending on how it is written.

Comment: @TimLeaf The input is contained in a variable and is not susceptible, because the value in that variable is not getting parsed. That is also how we can post code in here without this website being vulnerable to the code in the posts.

Comment: @TimLeaf you're right, it depends on how it's being called. However, if it's called as a stored procedure instead of executing a concatenated string, there shouldn't be a problem. The problem comes when you start concatenating values instead of parametrizing the calls to the database.

Comment: Right, I am talking about application code outside SQL. Because if there is any possibility of SQL injection, that is where it would happen, not within the stored procedure.

Comment: There is also possibly a risk of exceeding the max length of the varchar in this table, depending on how often it is called and how long the text provided is, since it is directly appending to the previous text every time without checking the current length.

Comment: @TimLeaf Yes, if the application is creating SQL statements by its own whim, then you are right. But in this case, the OP solution is safe of injection, Luis answer is correct.

Comment: *IF* what the OP has is open to injection, @TimLeaf it's not the SP that is, it's the OP's code in the **application**.  But, if that is the case, the OP is asking about the wrong thing and should be showing us his application code, not his SQL.

Comment: I agree, but I wanted to clarify that there could still be a risk elsewhere. Just because the OP didn't provide the code doesn't mean they should consider this resolved and forget about it. SQL injection has a tendency to strike from the places you'd least expect. If you want to be prepared to prevent it, it's really important to consider each step of the application framework, not only at the lowest level. The question asked of course has been answered. But it's not the full story of what the OP needs to examine to ensure safety.

Comment: @LuisCazares Ha!  I do indeed have a where clause.  I should have been more accurate.

Comment: Indeed the calling application needs to be safe, but I am really only worried here about the SQL procedure -- specifically that it can have anything passed to it and it won't be vulnerable to an injection attack.  (Yes it could be vulnerable to other things -- like exceeding max length.)

Comment: Then certainly, there is no risk of that, using a stored procedure like this. This is the safest way to do it.